# Error updating MySQL table from a foreach loop

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5

I am fetching rows from the database. Each row has 2 radio buttons. I am having issues updating these values in a table. I get this error -

Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::update() must be of the type array, string given

```
@foreach($items as $item)                 
    <td>{{ $item->item_title }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->description }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->price }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->quantity }}</td>
    <td>{{ $item->total }}</td>
    <td>
        <div class='btn-group'>
                <form action="{{url('lineManagerUpdateRequests')}}" method="post">

                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}][]" value="2"> Approve
                <input type="radio" name="item_id[{{$item->request_id}}][]" value="6"> Decline
            </div>
        </td>    
    @endforeach
    <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
</form>
```

This is my controller

```
foreach ($request->input('item_id') as $id => $value) {
            $update = DB::table('request_items')
                        ->where('id', $id)
                        ->update('line_manager_remark', $value);
}
```

Comment: Change the string to an array by casting.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
->update('line_manager_remark', $value);
```

try

```
->update(array('line_manager_remark' => $value));
```

or

```
->update(['line_manager_remark' => $value]);
```

as the argument of `update()` must be of the type array.

[Reference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#updates)

Comment: I get this error - preg_replace(): Parameter mismatch, pattern is a string while replacement is an array